# How to use a Map value in a match case statement in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a map like this:

```
val mealIdsMap: Map[String, String]    =
Map (
      "breakfast"     ->    "omelet",
      "lunch"         ->    "steak",
      "dinner"        ->    "salad"
)
```

Then I try to use it in a match statement like this:

```
"omelet" match 
{ 
  case mealIdsMap("breakfast") => "Thank God"
}
```

And I get this error:

```
error: value mealIdsMap is not a case class constructor,
nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq method
              case mealIdsMap("breakfast") => "Thank God"
```

Anyone know how to use a map like this in a match/case statement?

Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 7):

You should read what is the purpose of pattern matching from a tutorial, may be from [this one](http://kerflyn.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/playing-with-scalas-pattern-matching/) (first non trivial example on google).

You have inverted the test:

```
mealIdsMap("breakfast") match {
  case "omelet" => "Thank God"
  case _ => "Don't forget a default"
}
```

And if you're not sure that the key is present (and even if you are, if you want to write idiomatic scala, you should prefer:

```
mealIdsMap.get("breakfast") match {
  case Some("omelet") => "Thank God"
  case _ => "Don't forget a default"
}
```

Where `get`returns an option, avoiding you to try catch your code or to let it break silently.

Answer (score 2):

Though, its still interesting to try to achieve such a behavior. have a look at this example:

```
  case class InvMatcher (m:Map[String, String]){
 def unapply(v:String):Option[String] = {
   return m collectFirst {case (k, `v`) => k}
 }
```

}

This class helps you to inverse-match a map.
usage:

```
val ma = InvMatcher (Map (
  "breakfast"     ->    "omelet",
  "lunch"         ->    "steak",
  "dinner"        ->    "salad"
));

"steak" match {
  case ma(s) => s match {
    case "breakfast" => print("Thank God")
    case "lunch" => print("whatever")

    case _ => print("dont forget default")
  }
  case _ => print("dont forget default")
}
```

This is nearly as you wanted it though you need a second match-statement (which doesnt need a default case here...)

Comment: May be a bit early to introduce unapply magic for covenantis and I'm pretty sure a nicer implementation can be performed.

Comment: I had a deeper look a it: you can replace  your unapply code with: `m collectFirst {case (k, \`v\`) => k}`

Comment: changed the example, though i still need a guard, as i dont want to test 'v' but the value of v

Comment: This is exacly the purpose of the backquotes (`\`v\``). furthermore, in the second part, you need 2 default cases (one for each `match`).